# Shouldn't my answer in Law Meta be reinstated? (abuse of flags)

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

A user posted on Law Meta [this question](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/975/how-can-we-advertise-law-se-on-legal-reddits) after learning that the activity levels on Law SE are pretty low. I posted [my answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/978/2) yesterday, and it was deleted/hidden & locked by Community few hours ago because "*[i]t was flagged as spam or offensive content*".

My answer cannot be considered spam, since it does not advertise any commercial services. Quite the contrary, it discourages the idea of resorting to SE's competitors. The answer contains several links, all of them being Law SE posts on which I support my answer.

The answer does address some users' (including a new Law SE moderator's) unfortunate propensity to downvote and close/VTC posts. Although I did not name the other [non-moderator] user who has that propensity, identifying him is trivial because his pattern of downvoting questions is evident from the multiple links I provided. But that user's pattern is not my answer's fault. For the record, by the time of getting locked & hidden, my answer had gotten two downvotes.

Although my [answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/978/revisions) might make the alluded users uncomfortable, there is nothing in it that can be reasonably considered "offensive", "rude", or "abusive" so as to get flagged, let alone suppressed. The fact that someone gets uncomfortable by the objectively verifiable arguments in an answer does not imply that the answer is offensive.

It is ironic and shady that my answer on Law Meta promotes being more welcoming to the audience and yet it gets flagged (of course, from the comfort zone of anonymity).

Comment: Posting here brings a broader audience, but you'll find much fewer people with the required reputation to see your deleted post.

Comment: If you have an issue with the moderation of one specific answer on Law Meta, you should take it up there, since this site is only about the general network. If you have an issue with moderators on Law Meta, you can contact the CMs via the [contact form](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/contact), _I want to appeal a code of conduct violation_ seems most applicable.

Comment: @Tom I understand. Should I copy/paste here (and/or a new post on Law Meta) the answer at issue?

Comment: @ErikA Thank you for the hint & link.

Comment: Depends. When you really want to keep this question here and not ask it on LawMeta or using the "contact us" link, then you can paste the answer here, or post a Screenshot of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Issues like this are best addressed directly on the meta site in question, or, if that avenue has been unsuccessful and you still want to appeal, to the community team directly via the "contact us" button.

MSE has more people, but very few of us (comparatively) are active on Law.SE. In addition to that, even among those who are, only the moderators can really do something about that. Your best bet is posting to the Law.SE meta and addressing it there.